# Certification failed in Windows Store

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, certificate

**I need help how to synchronize a Windows Phone app with Push notification and the Windows Store.**

The Windows Phone 8.1 (VS2013 Express) solution is working in Emulator for working with Push notifications. It is possible to send the client (Emulator) the push notification and he will display it on Mobilephone.

**How to get it in official [store](https://dev.windowsphone.com/)**?

I have tried with Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Phone 8.0. (Is working in Emulator)
Also with 
Visual Studio 2013 Express and Windows Phone 8.1. (Is working in Emulator)

The guidelines are not helpfull because the menus are described for "[Windows Store](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Toast-Notification-In-4f981164)" instead for "Windows Phone" or they are [not described for using in the store](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Toast-Notification-Sample-fb20ae13) described with [different menus](https://docs.gamesparks.net/uncategorized/how-to-configure-windows-phone-push-notifications) I have never seen.

The current feedback of store is:
Missing certificat for authenticated push notifications: Certificate for authenticated push notifications.

`Package.appxmanifest`:

`<Identity Name="XXXXmobile-prototyping.XXXXX" Publisher="CN=0C8E935E-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX" Version="1.0.0.0" />`

[image: Push notification error]

Comment: Did you checked [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202940(v=vs.105).aspx)?

Comment: Problem is not the push-notification itself. That is working. Also in Emulator you need to follow the rules. Your link does not show how to work with the "<identity " flag which the store shares for giving the permission. I need any tutorial how to synchronize the Windows Store and Windows Phone certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dismiss the waring!

The solution is, just ignore the warning. It is no real error, it is an warning for using more than 500 message per day. The warning message just does not contain any information about the real reason of warning.

After submitting the app, it can use notification messages without any certificate.